# geth error - Fatal: Database has receipts with a legacy format

Tags: private-blockchain, error, database, geth-clique

I'm following this [tutorial](https://coinsbench.com/create-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-network-829be72658a5) for testing an ethereum private blockchain using 3 nodes.

Everything works fine but if I stop the nodes I can't restart them using the same command. Each node was running in a [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) session and I stopped the node with Ctrl+c in each screen session (which I think is not a proper way to stop a node...)

I'm new to blockchain and I have no idea how to fix this. I didn't find any relevant informations about this error.

The above command start the first node but I get the same error for the two other nodes.

```
geth --datadir "node1" --port "30311" --http --http.addr "127.0.0.1" --http.port "8501" --http.api "personal,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner" --networkid 34070 --bootnodes "enode://f691bfb1fc9f172305c8403b46ab89114f662a30efdf3fa0c09150fe4f2fef41a8e9ec3b64f428e852a287d392dfd46d226b6f4b40ee3587489a483dba0e4966@127.0.0.1:30312" --miner.gasprice "0" --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "0x854C8341d979237AEDbD806C72dA8CF6dE4E48DC" --mine console
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.303] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.310] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.326] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
WARN [07-14|14:48:13.342] Sanitizing invalid miner gas price       provided=0 updated=1,000,000,000
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.342] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.342] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/debian/ethereum/node1/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=524,288
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.511] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/debian/ethereum/node1/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.538]  
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.538] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.539] Chain ID:  48722 (unknown) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.539] Consensus: Clique (proof-of-authority) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.540]  
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.540] Pre-Merge hard forks: 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.540]  - Homestead:                   0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.541]  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): 0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.541]  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): 0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.542]  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): 0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.542]  - Byzantium:                   0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.542]  - Constantinople:              0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.543]  - Petersburg:                  0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.543]  - Istanbul:                    0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.544]  - Berlin:                      <nil> (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.544]  - London:                      <nil> (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.544]  
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.545] Merge not configured! 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.545]  - Hard-fork specification: https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md) 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.545] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.546]  
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.548] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=34070 dbversion=8
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.627] Loaded most recent local header          number=101,101 hash=76129b..b09047 td=201,876 age=1h48m6s
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.627] Loaded most recent local full block      number=101,101 hash=76129b..b09047 td=201,876 age=1h48m6s
INFO [07-14|14:48:13.627] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=101,101 hash=76129b..b09047 td=201,876 age=1h48m6s
INFO [07-14|14:48:14.580] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [07-14|14:48:14.580] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.581] Switch sync mode from snap sync to full sync 
INFO [07-14|14:48:14.582] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:04:46+0000 age=1h43m28s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:06:04+0000 age=1h42m10s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:06:53+0000 age=1h41m21s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:09:15+0000 age=1h38m59s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:12:30+0000 age=1h35m44s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:21:26+0000 age=1h26m48s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.584] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:34:16+0000 age=1h13m58s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.585] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:40:35+0000 age=1h7m39s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.585] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:41:56+0000 age=1h6m18s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.585] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T13:45:12+0000 age=1h3m2s
WARN [07-14|14:48:14.585] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2022-07-14T14:46:34+0000 age=1m40s
Fatal: Database has receipts with a legacy format. Please run `geth db freezer-migrate`.
```

The recommended command doesn't help

```
geth db freezer-migrate
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.511] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.512] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.517] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.518] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/debian/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=524,288
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.638] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/debian/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.638] No receipts in freezer to migrate 
INFO [07-14|14:49:55.638] Freezer shutting down
```

After that If I restart the node I get the same error again.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered same issue, I believe it's go ethereum bug. As of geth 1.10.21 there is param that you can set - `--ignore-legacy-receipts` which will cause geth to ignore this check before starting up

Update:
This was indeed geth's bug, see [github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/25498). Bug fix was merged. I assume the fix will be published in next (right now version is `v1.10.23`) release.